# Catch missing dependency (dll) from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, exe, errorlevel

Can I catch the error when an EXE with missing dependency is run from inside a batch?
In such case the EXE fails to load and our app logs are empty

I tried checking the errorlevel and even tried to pre-check the EXE using depends.exe tool
however non of them worked

i.e. mybat.exe

run-this-app.exe
do some check.. do something

Comment: You can catch the application output. Is that what you need?

Comment: There is no output if the application is not loading due to missing dependencies.. that is exactly my problem

Comment: Usually, if an executable does not find a dependency, it throws exception in Error out. So it can be caught. This applies mostly on console applications, UI ones can throw errors in MessageBox.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know what the dependencies are and the location then you can check for them.

```
if not exist "%windir%\system32\dependency1" goto :msg
if not exist "%windir%\system32\dependency2" goto :msg
if not exist "%windir%\system32\dependency3" goto :msg
if not exist "%windir%\system32\dependency4" goto :msg

:: batch code here

goto :EOF    
:msg
echo you need the extra xyz filez...
```

Comment: In this way I will have to update my script for each application or version. I am looking for more generic solution. I am looking for a way to recognize this error without explicitly check each dependency.